# GoogleAdsence show all over the page

Tags: php, html, css, adsense

I am generate a google adsense code for my website to add in the header section of website.But its show the add all over the page. On header footer and also in middle of the page. here is the code I am using

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <script>
      (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
        google_ad_client: "ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        enable_page_level_ads: true
      });
    </script>
</div>
```

This wrapper div is on the header on left side. How can I place ad on one position on one page.?

Comment: I guess to just make a div and place your ad script in it? The ad appears where you put it in your code. There's no magic in there.

Comment: I did that but its not show on the position where i place and showing on another 2  3 different position on same page @MartinJoneš

Comment: Make yourself div with set height and width, set background color and style your div how you want. If it appears okey, try to place your ad. I think that nothing should change.

Comment: okay let me try it this @MartinJoneš

Comment: check here http://chandigarhpropertyonline.com/ I place a div with background but its not showing on head but all over the html page @MartinJoneš

Comment: is there any setting I have to do in google adsense for show on particular position @MartinJoneš

Comment: Dude, you have more ads than a p0rn site. No, Google ads are being placed regarding to your set div.

Comment: yeah I know there are many ads. I just want it one add on the page on one position that what I want @MartinJoneš

Comment: Just put your script on that position. There is nothing hard on that. And I don't know why you used PHP tag when this is not PHP related at all

Comment: see my html here I place it exact like what you are saying http://prntscr.com/g880e3

Comment: You are probably using some CMS because the code you provided is not clear at all. Check your CMS documentation and the template creator.

Comment: its core php @MartinJoneš